# React — onClick handler in Btn component AND parent

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I have a Btn component with some style toggles in an onClick inside that component.

I want to add an onClick to the parent to carry out a function when the button is clicked. The btn component will be reused so the onClick in the parent component will change, while the onClick in the Btn component will always only just toggle btn styles.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/69z2wepo/49519/)

```
class BtnParent extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.alsoDoThis = this.alsoDoThis.bind(this);
  }
  alsoDoThis() {
    alert('clicked');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <BtnFav onClick={this.alsoDoThis} />
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: `<BtnFav alsoDoThis={this.alsoDoThis} />`?

Answer (score 0):

You pass the `onClick` prop to the child but you never use it.The function needs to be invoked explicitly:

```
 handleClick() {
    this.props.onClick(); // invoke it anywhere in the child
    this.setState({favorited: !this.state.favorited});
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

btnParent.jsx below:

```
class BtnParent extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.alsoDoThis = this.alsoDoThis.bind(this);
  }
  alsoDoThis() {
    alert('clicked');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <BtnFav alsoDoThis={this.alsoDoThis} />
    );
  }
};
```

btnFav.jsx below:

```
class BtnFav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.alsoDoThis} />
    );
  }
};
```

can solve it!

---

Component communication between parent and child, you can use react props to pass the `function`, but when two components are not parent / child, you can use some event publish / subscribe lib. such as https://github.com/hustcc/onfire.js

Comment: This makes the alert('clicked') work, but it breaks the style change handled within the button component. Here is an updated fiddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49594/

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
   class BtnFav extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <button onClick={()=>this.props.alsoDoThis()} />
        );
      }
    };
```